# C# Asynchronous IO: Is there a way of ensuring ordering of tasks?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, system, threadpool

I would like to use asynchronous io for socket communication with a distributed hash server. Environment is C# 3.5, but could use 4.0 if necessary.

Suppose I issue the following asynchronous commands (in pseudocode):

```
socket.set_asynch("FOO","bar");
string rc = socket.get_asynch("FOO");
```

Since asynchronous io uses the system thread pool, the two commands may be run on two
different threads. How can I ensure that rc equals "bar"? i.e. that the first command
is issued before the second command is issued?

Thanks!

Comment: Use synchronous IO?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I lol'd, but it's true.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Framework to control asynchronous behavior?

Comment: Well..................asynch means I can do things between set and get, if I need to, as opposed to waiting for a network response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could design your API around the [Task<T> class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) (Task Parallel Library):

```
class DistributedHashTable
{
    public Task SetAsync(string key, string value);

    public Task<string> GetAsync(string key);
}
```

Both methods would use asynchronous IO to perform the respective operation, and set the returned Task<T> to completed when the operation has finished.

Then you could use your class synchronously like this:

```
var dht = new DistributedHashTable(...);

dht.SetAsync("FOO", "bar").Wait();

Console.WriteLine(dht.GetAsync("FOO").Result);
```

or asynchronously like this:

```
var dht = new DistributedHashTable(...);

dht.SetAsync("FOO", "bar")
   .ContinueWith(t => dht.GetAsync("FOO"))
   .Unwrap()
   .ContinueWith(t => {
                          Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
                      });
```

or asynchronously using the [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) like this:

```
var dht = new DistributedHashTable(...);

await dht.SetAsync("FOO", "bar");

Console.WriteLine(await dht.GetAsync("FOO"));
```